# Date returning as "Undefined" and "NaN" in some browsers?

Tags: javascript, json, date, undefined, nan

I have been working this morning on creating a web app that takes information from a JSON file - in this case, tweet information from the @POTUS account, as The White House just made a ton of information publically accessible - and presents it on the screen.

Specifically, I have been working on taking the JSON file of @POTUS tweet information, and displaying the text of the tweet, and the date. The date is taken from a timestamp, and I have used a bit of JS to translate it into a format that is appealing to me.

My problem is this: the date shows up correctly in Chrome (where I have been testing), but when viewing it in Safari, Firefox, or a mobile device, the date returns "undefined NaN, NaN", where month is returning "undefined" and day and year are both returning "NaN". Looking through my code, I cannot find a reason why this would be happening.

Here is my HTML file in it's entirety:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>@POTUS</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,900" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="tweet-container">
         <header>
            <h1 class="title">
               <a class="twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/potus" target="_blank">@POTUS</a> Tweets
            </h1>
            <p class="description">A complete archieve of tweets from President Barack Obama, presented in reverse chronological order.</p>
         </header>
         <div id="potus-tweets"></div>
         <button id="btn">New Tweet</button>
      </div>
      <script src="assets/js/tweets.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS file in it's entirety:

```
var tweetCounter = 0;
var tweetsContainer = document.getElementById("potus-tweets");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'assets/js/potus.json');
  request.onload = function(){
    var potusTweets = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    loadTweets(potusTweets);
  };
  request.send();
});

function loadTweets(data){

  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var date = new Date(data[tweetCounter].timestamp);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var day = date.getDate();

  var tweet = "";

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    tweet += '<div class="tweet"><p class="copy">' + data[tweetCounter].text + '</p><p class="date">' + monthNames[month] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year + '</p></div>';
    tweetCounter++;
  };

  tweetsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tweet);
};
```

For reference, the project is live here: http://thejessicafelts.github.io/projects/POTUS-Tweets/

And the code can be found here: https://github.com/thejessicafelts/POTUS-Tweets

Any insights as to why this isn't working would be extremely appreciated. I have been trying to troubleshoot this all morning, and I cannot see anything that would be causing the return of "undefined NaN, NaN".

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this the link you're making a GET request to ?https://github.com/thejessicafelts/POTUS-Tweets/assets/js/potus.json I need it to debug this code on both browsers (if yes, then I am getting an {error: not found})

Comment: Nevermind, I got the link.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a sample of the timestamp as it was an important piece of input which is missing in the question.

```
{ // A sample tweet in your array.
  "tweet_id": 796018814072672300,
  "in_reply_to_status_id": "",
  "in_reply_to_user_id": "",
  "timestamp": "2016-11-08 15:57:29 +0000",
  "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
  "text": "Today, progress is on the ballot. Go vote - then make sure your friends, your family, and everyone you know votes too.",
  "retweeted_status_id": "",
  "retweeted_status_user_id": "",
  "retweeted_status_timestamp": "",
  "expanded_urls": ""
}
```

With that put up for reference I would link to the MDN doc for the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor.

```
//Syntax:
new Date(); [1]
new Date(value); [2]
new Date(dateString); [3]
new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]); [4]
```

From the object I picked up from your [json](https://github.com/thejessicafelts/POTUS-Tweets/blob/master/assets/js/potus.json) asset, and then following this description, you are using the third syntax. I'll quote from the documentation that the `dateString` argument must comply with the `date.parse` method

> dateString
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Coming closer to the cause of your problem, I'll mention the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for `date.parse`

> dateString
>
> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

Yes, unexpected. Further down in the description you may find:-

> Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent, especially across different ECMAScript implementations where strings like "2015-10-12 12:00:00" may be parsed to as NaN, UTC or local timezone.

Now that sounds familiar.

I tested the same string without the timezone offset on firefox 47.0.2

```
var a = new Date("2016-11-08 15:57:29")
a.getDate()
// returns 8
a.getMonth()
//returns 10
a.getFullYear()
//returns 2016
```

Comment: `new Date("2016-11-08 15:57:29")` returns NaN in Safari. Don't parse strings with the Date constructor (it's equivalent to Date.parse for parsing), use a small function or library.

Comment: I understand. I was just giving a test situation where it works in firefox. I do have it included in my answer that the datestring approach can have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `timestamp` to milliseconds, then feed them the Date() constructor:

`var a = Date(<date in milliseconds>);`